# how to force file download instead of opening in any application

Tags: vb.net, download

I want to prompt users to save file instead of opening file in application. For example if user click a mp3 file link....mp3 file must not be open in win media player...instead user promoted to download that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment; filename=filename.mp3`.  This will suggest to the browser that it should prompt the user to save as the given file name.

Comment: @m.qayyum: `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & file.Name)`

Comment: Error='Response' is not declared.

Comment: @m.qayyum: Where are you adding this code?  Try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response` instead, though I imagine this code _should_ be going somewhere that already has `Response` referenced (such as the code-behind for a page, since it's most certainly display logic).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just send a content-disposition header. I.e.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>
```

And that should force the option to download the file.